# Inserting quotes into the string representation of a 2D list in Python

Tags: python, string, casting, user-input, plotly-dash

I have code that takes user input from a text box and needs to convert this into a 2D list of strings. The user input is a Jupyter Dash text input

I am trying to design it in such a way that the user does not need to quote the elements themselves and can enter the words comma separated

I have it working if the user *does* quote the element themselves but think it would be cleaner if they don't have to

I could achieve this with a lot of `str.split()` and `str.replace()` but it is obviously very messy and liable to breaking easily

If there is a way with Dash to circumvent this issue altogether I would be very interested but I could not find one

**Current functionality**
Input (external quotes not written by user but implied):
`'["apple", "orange", "pear"], ["cabbage", "lettuce"]'`

Output:
`[["apple", "orange", "pear"], ["cabbage", "lettuce"]]`

**Desired functionality**
Input (external quotes not written by user but implied):
`'[apple, orange, pear], [cabbage, lettuce]'`

Output:
`[["apple", "orange", "pear"], ["cabbage", "lettuce"]]`

**My current solution is as follows:**

```
user_input = f"[{user_input}]"`
```

I would really like to avoid the use of `literal_eval()` but it was the only solution I found that wasn't excessive string manipulation

```
output_list = list(ast.literal_eval(user_input))
```

Comment: This would be extremely trivial if you could accept the input as *multiple lines* of comma separated strings. Requiring `[]` as delimiters means you'll need a more complex parser… (even though a regex would probably suffice here)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach using [regular expressions module `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

input_str = '["apple", "orange", "pear"], ["cabbage", "lettuce"]'

lst2nd_level = []
for inner_list in re.findall('\[([\"a-z, ]+)\]', input_str):
    lst = list(re.findall('\"([a-z]+)\"', inner_list))
    lst2nd_level.append(lst)

print(lst2nd_level)
```

Where the first regular expression is matching lists of strings and the second matches words in the internal lists.